# Prove that if $0 < a,b,c <1$, then $\sqrt{abc}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)} < 1$.

Tags: inequality

> Prove that if $0 < a,b,c <1$, then $\sqrt{abc}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)} < 1$.

I think that using AM-GM might work. Thus we have $\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)} \geq \sqrt{abc}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}$ but I am not sure how to proceed. Maybe the maximum occurs when $a=b=c$ but how to prove that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $c<1$ and $1-c<1$ so :

$$\sqrt{abc}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}<\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}$$

Now use AM-GM :

$$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)} \leq \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{(1-a)+(1-b)}{2} =1$$ and so the conclusion follows .

Answer (score 7):

Take $a=\sin^2\alpha,b=\sin^2\beta,c=\sin^2\gamma$, with $0<\alpha,\beta,\gamma<\pi/2$.

We now have to prove that $\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma+\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma<1$.

But $\sin\gamma,\cos\gamma<1$ gives us that

$\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma+\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma<\sin\alpha\sin\beta+\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\cos(\alpha-\beta)\leq1$, and we're done.